# Inserting JavaScript into HTML body always appears at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to put a JavaScript "wheel of fortune" into my HTML body `<div>` but every time it appears at the bottom of the whole HTML.

I have:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phaser.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is the game.js

```
// the game itself
var game;
// the spinning wheel
var wheel; 
// can the wheel spin?
var canSpin;
// slices (prizes) placed in the wheel
var slices = 8;
// prize names, starting from 12 o'clock going clockwise
var slicePrizes = ["VYHRAL SI", "Bohužial si nevyhral.", "Skús zatočiť znova!", "Bohužial si nevyhral.", "Vyhral si zľavu", "Bohužial si nevyhral.", "Skús zatočiť znova!", "Bohužial si nevyhral."];
// the prize you are about to win
var prize;
// text field where to show the prize
var prizeText;

window.onload = function() {    
     // creation of a 458x488 game
    game = new Phaser.Game(458, 488, Phaser.AUTO, "");
     // adding "PlayGame" state
     game.state.add("PlayGame",playGame);
     // launching "PlayGame" state
     game.state.start("PlayGame");
}

// PLAYGAME STATE

var playGame = function(game){};

playGame.prototype = {
     // function to be executed once the state preloads
     preload: function(){
          // preloading graphic assets
          game.load.image("wheel", "wheel.png");
        game.load.image("stred", "stred.png");     
     },
     // funtion to be executed when the state is created
    create: function(){
          // giving some color to background
        game.stage.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
          // adding the wheel in the middle of the canvas
        wheel = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.width / 2, "wheel");
          // setting wheel registration point in its center
          wheel.anchor.set(0.5);
          // adding the pin in the middle of the canvas
          var pin = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.width / 2, "stred");
          // setting pin registration point in its center
          pin.anchor.set(0.5);
          // adding the text field
          prizeText = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, 480, "");
          // setting text field registration point in its center
          prizeText.anchor.set(0.5);
          // aligning the text to center
          prizeText.align = "center";
          // the game has just started = we can spin the wheel
          canSpin = true;
          // waiting for your input, then calling "spin" function
          game.input.onDown.add(this.spin, this);       
    },
     // function to spin the wheel
     spin(){
          // can we spin the wheel?
          if(canSpin){  
               // resetting text field
               prizeText.text = "";
               // the wheel will spin round from 2 to 4 times. This is just coreography
               var rounds = game.rnd.between(2, 4);
               // then will rotate by a random number from 0 to 360 degrees. This is the actual spin
               var degrees = game.rnd.between(0, 360);
               // before the wheel ends spinning, we already know the prize according to "degrees" rotation and the number of slices
               prize = slices - 1 - Math.floor(degrees / (360 / slices));
               // now the wheel cannot spin because it's already spinning
               canSpin = false;
               // animation tweeen for the spin: duration 3s, will rotate by (360 * rounds + degrees) degrees
               // the quadratic easing will simulate friction
               var spinTween = game.add.tween(wheel).to({
                    angle: 360 * rounds + degrees
               }, 3000, Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.Out, true);
               // once the tween is completed, call winPrize function
               spinTween.onComplete.add(this.winPrize, this);
          }
     },
     // function to assign the prize
     winPrize(){
          // now we can spin the wheel again
          canSpin = true;
          // writing the prize you just won
          prizeText.text = slicePrizes[prize];
     }
}// JavaScript Document
```

It should look like this:
[image]

but somehow it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Don't you have a div#something specified for your game ?

Comment: we need to see the relevant part of the js that adds the element to the DOM

Comment: Your script position doesn't mean that is where your markup will go. For us to help you we would need to see your javascript code. The JS will have things like `document.getElement...` that will grab elements it's expecting to see on the page in order to place your wheel in the correct element. You also need to use CSS to aid in layout.

Comment: If the body contains only 2 scripts, where do the blue and orange banners come from? Are they generated inside the code? What styles do all elements have?

Comment: @R.Schifini blue is just another div with blue background and those orange things are css buttons

Comment: @scrappedcola ok, i added the whole game.js. Im pretty new to this so thank you for patience :D

Comment: @Romanidez Please hold on, your question will be probably reopen soon and then people will be able to answer it

Comment: reopened, thanks SOCVR :)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526933/html-moving-phaser-into-container-div). "The 4th parameter to the Phaser.Game constructor is the parent container. If you leave it empty it will inject the canvas into the document body. "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML moving phaser into container div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526933/html-moving-phaser-into-container-div)

Comment: You are leaving the fourth parameter empty. `game = new Phaser.Game(458, 488, Phaser.AUTO, "");` The game will end up in the body after your banner and buttons and not between them.

Comment: So i changed the first line to var game = new Phaser.Game(458, 458, Phaser.AUTO, "hra");
then added <div id="hra"></div> and how i have a huge black block there.